# Jmeter in Docker

Tags: docker, jmeter

I am trying to run Jmeter in Docker. I got Dockerfile and Entrypoint has entrypoint.sh as well added.

```
ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.2.1"
RUN mkdir /jmeter
WORKDIR /jmeter
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install wget -y \
    && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y \
    && wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz \
    && tar -xzf apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz \
    && rm apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz
ENV JAVA_HOME  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
RUN export JAVA_HOME
RUN echo $JAVA_HOME
ENV JMETER jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN
RUN export JMETER
RUN echo $JMETER
WORKDIR /jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1
COPY users.jmx /jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1
COPY entrypoint.sh /jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Inspired from https://github.com/hhcordero/docker-jmeter-client
# Basically runs jmeter, assuming the PATH is set to point to JMeter bin-dir (see Dockerfile)
#
# This script expects the standdard JMeter command parameters.
#
set -e
freeMem=`awk '/MemFree/ { print int($2/1024) }' /proc/meminfo`
s=$(($freeMem/10*8))
x=$(($freeMem/10*8))
n=$(($freeMem/10*2))
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmn${n}m -Xms${s}m -Xmx${x}m"

echo "START Running Jmeter on `date`"
echo "JVM_ARGS=${JVM_ARGS}"
echo "jmeter args=$@"

# Keep entrypoint simple: we must pass the standard JMeter arguments
bin/jmeter.sh $@
echo "END Running Jmeter on `date`"
```

Now when I try to run container without jmeter arguments, container starts and asks for jmeter arguments

```
docker run sar/test12
```

I get error as An error occurred:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

But when i run jmeter container with arguments
`docker run -v /home/jmeter/unbuntjmeter/:/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1 sar/test12 -n -t ./users.jmx`

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "./entrypoint.sh": permission denied": unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solutions

For the X11 issue, you can try setting `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` in your `docker run`, you may need to perform some other steps to get it working properly depending on how your host is setup.  But trying to get the GUI working here seems like overkill.  To fix your problem when you pass through the command arguments, you can either:

- Add execute permissions to the `entrypoint.sh` file on your host by running `chmod +x /home/jmeter/unbuntjmeter/entrypoint.sh`.

Or

- Don't mount `/home/jmeter/unbuntjmeter/` into the container by removing the `-v` argument from your `docker run` command.

### Problem

When you run this command `docker run -v /home/jmeter/unbuntjmeter/:/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1 sar/test12 -n -t ./users.jmx`, you are mounting the directory `/home/jmeter/unbuntjmeter/` from your host machine onto `/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1` in your docker container.

That means your `/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/entrypoint.sh` script in the container is being overwritten by the one in that directory on your host (if there is one, which there does seem to be).  This file on your host machine doesn't have the proper permissions to be executed in your container (presumably it just needs `+x` because you are running this in your build: `RUN ["chmod", "+x", "entrypoint.sh"]`).

Comment: yes, i have entrypoint.sh in my host volume mount.